# Removing a CSS rule that's applied to all elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a problem with being unable to remove a rule that is applied to all elements. First of all, apologies but I could not upload a JSfiddle to this post - the page URL is: http://www.chessdroids.com/matches/long/test2.html

The problem is the CSS rule ‘* { text-align: center }’ is being used throughout the site and I cannot remove this, but it is making the chess board align incorrectly. Removing the rule works but destroys other areas of the site.

How can I remove this rule to the chess board only? I have tried using the not selector and canvas-board > * {display:none !important} but to no avail (note that I made the red canvas-board div wrap just to wrap the chess board). FYI I am using the canvas chess viewer: http://www.canvaschess.com/pgn_install.php.

Any help would be greatly appreciated here as I’m unsure how to fix this, thank you.

Comment: Using `float: left;` for `.chessboard` and then `overflow: hidden;` for `.pgn_main_box ` should solve the issue.

Comment: The "cascade" in "Cascading Style Sheets" means that later or more specific rules override earlier, less specific ones. Override this the same way you'd override anything anywhere in CSS; specify a rule to do that.

Comment: thank you. how did you know to target these 2 selectors? I'm also trying to remove the white background around the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.canvaschesspgn .pgn_main_box {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: thanks! how did you know to target these 2 selectors? I'm also trying to remove the white background around the text

Comment: I inspected the page and saw that .pgn_main_box was a child element of .canvashesspgn.

Regarding the background:

.canvaschesspgn .pgn_main_box .move_list {
    backgtound: transparent;
}

Since .move_list is a child of .pgn_main_box

Comment: This is not the correct answer since the only thing that align:left is doing is making a new rule. You should use the unset prop for this. Look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

try

```css
    .canvaschesspgn > * {
      text-align: left;
    }
```

Comment: This is not a good approach. Later on, if the user wants to make it center he will then override the rules

Comment: a declaration like he has on '*' selector its not a good approach to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.chessboard {
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 33%);
    outline: 0 none;
}
```

to

```
.chessboard {
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 33%);
    display: block !important;
    outline: 0 none;
}
```

So text-align does not apply only to the chessboard

Answer (score -1):

If you want to reset anything you can use this

```
* {
text-align: unset;
}
```

that should do it, enjoy

and here are the [css doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/unset)

Comment: But he says that that rule is "being used throughout the site and I cannot remove it", which is equivalent to what you are proposing.